# Кодирование строки. Алгоритм на PHP для конвертирования колонки excel в его порядковый номер?

Tags: php, excel, алгоритм

Подскажите алгоритм, который мог бы преобразовать строку в число.

```
A = 1
B = 2
c = 3
...
Z = 26
AA = 27
AB = 28
AC = 29 
...
```

ABA = ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот как-то так пишу без проверки кода потому может с ошибками:

```
$letters = str_split('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
$letters = array_flip($letters);

$variant = 'ABA';

$newVariant = str_split($variant);
$sum = 0;

foreach($newVariant as $items){
   $sum *= 26;
   $sum+= ($letters[$items]+1);
}

echo $sum;
```

Проверил и поправил